# Animate an SVG replacement in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using a set of sliders to generate an SVG image in d3. Whenever a slider changes, my corresponding SVG image should change.

To generate my SVG, I'm using the following code -

```
function build_svg(json_data) {
    d3.select(".col-sm-6").select("svg").remove();
    var svg = d3.select(".col-sm-6").append("svg")
        .attr("width", diameter)
        .attr("height", diameter)
        .attr("class", "bubble");
    d3.json(json_data, function(error, data) {
        // Some logic to populate variable "svg"
    }
}
```

The function `build_svg` is called whenever I want to put a new set of JSON data.
Unfortunately, every time I move my slider, I see a flickering image and I don't observe a smooth transition between the SVG images. What would be the best way to  build this animation?

Comment: @RobertLongson does this help?

Comment: Please create an [mcve] ideally as a Stack Snippet.

Comment: @martianwars Bear in mind that `d3.json` is asynchronous. Depending on the size of the JSON, the callback can take several milliseconds to run. The best idea is downloading all the data before and wrapping the slider function inside the callback.

Comment: Yes, all my data is local. @GerardoFurtado